# Let $\lambda_2=\lambda \otimes \lambda$ be the product lebesgue measure. Is the unit disk $\lambda_2$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I a having some difficulty with this question. It is somewhat alien to me and in my linear analysis course Fubini's theorem was not covered so I would prefer an answer that doesn't use that.

My question is this:

Let $\lambda_2=\lambda \otimes \lambda$ be the product Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $D$ be the closed disk of radius 1 centred at $(0,0)$. Is $D$ $\lambda_2$-measurable? Justify your answer.

Comment: I am kind of rusty on measure theory, but isn't the product of 2 1-dimensional Lebesgue measures on $\mathbb{R}$ the same as the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Anyway, it sounds like a homework problem. Try to show what you have tried out, which approach to measure theory you are using, and so on.

Comment: It is the product of 2 1 dimensional lebesgue measures, but I am having some difficulty as to what I have tried to measure. I have defined D={(x,y): x^2 +y^2 =1}, and I have thought that as it is a closet set and all closed sets are borel measurable, but so it must be lebesgue measurable.  But I really want a more analytical approach.

Comment: The closed disk is $D = \{(x,y);x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \}$. What you wrote is correct otherwise. What kind of other proof are you seeking?

Comment: You could say fill the disk $D$ with little squares inside, up to $\epsilon$, and cover $D$ with another set of little squares, up to $\epsilon$ also. If you do that for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, this would give another proof. It is kind of similar to what Archimedes used to do by the way, to estimate lengths, areas, volumes etc.

Comment: I do not follow how that process would answer the question?

Comment: well, it depends on which equivalent approach you are using to define the Lebesgue measure. If I recall correctly, what I wrote is closer to the Caratheodory approach. Anyway, try to apply the set of definitions you are using, and you should be good. If you want, edit your question to explain a bit more what kind of proof you are looking for.

Comment: okay :) I ill look at the Carathedory approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal M$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of $\lambda$-measurable sets on $\mathbb R$. The $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ that contains all rectangles (that is sets of the form $A\times B$, where $A,B \in \mathcal M$). Note that all open intervals in $\mathbb R$ are members of $\mathcal M$ . Now let $\{x_n\}$ be a enumaration of points $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q | (x,y) \not \in D\}$. Now for each $n$ let $R_n$ be the cartesian product of two open intervals such that $R_n\cap D = \emptyset$ (can be done since $\mathbb R^2 \setminus D$ is open). Note now that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty R_n = \mathbb R^2 \setminus D$. So $\mathbb R^2 \setminus D $ is product-measurable. Thus so is $D = (\cup_{n=1}^\infty R_n)^C$.

**Edit:**
The sets $R_n$ are defined to have center $x_n$, which is needed. Also I might need to control the size of the rectangles are not too small in order for them to corver $\mathbb R^2 \setminus D$. Say $r_n = \frac{|x_n|-1}{2}$ and let $R_n = (x_n^1-r_n;x_n^1+r_n)\times(x_n^2-r_n;x_n^2+r_n)$, where $x_n = (x_n^1,x_n^2)$.

Comment: nice clear proof! You may want to add that each $R_n$ contains $x_n$, which is probably what you meant (just a minor comment). Nice proof.

Comment: why do we take an enumeration of only the rational numbers?

Comment: @Catherine... For measurability we need to get a *countable* union.  The rationals is just a convenient countable dense set.

Comment: okay thank you so much!